# Unable to center divs

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a div that is unable to be centered. I can't seem to figure out what is the issue even after `margin: 0 auto` and setting a explicit width. Would like to know what is wrong with it and how to I solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

```
 <div class="services-container">
        <h1 class="header-title banner">Services</h1>
        <div class="service-items">
            <div class="service-item">
                <span class="icon-box icon"></span><h2 class="service-title">Moving</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam laoreet nisl sed placerat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dits mcorper semper nibh ac auctor. </p>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="service-item">
                 <span class="icon-box icon"></span><h2 class="service-title">Delivery</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam laoreet nisl sed placerat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dits mcorper semper nibh ac auctor. </p>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>    
            <div class="service-item">
                <span class="icon-box icon"></span><h2 class="service-title">Accounting</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam laoreet nisl sed placerat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dits mcorper semper nibh ac auctor. </p>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>    
            <div class="service-item">
                 <span class="icon-box icon"></span><h2 class="service-title">IT Services</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam laoreet nisl sed placerat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dits mcorper semper nibh ac auctor. </p>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    div.services-container {
    margin-top: 1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.service-items {
    max-width: 1280px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.service-item {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:45%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: width:45% has no reference to be applied. no width is set in .service-items, so they use all space avalaible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/cavat/2/edit)**

```
div.service-items {
    background:#eee;
    max-width: 1280px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; /* ADD */
}

div.service-item {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:45%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin:0 auto;
    /*float:left;*/       /* REMOVE */
    display:inline-block; /* ADD */
    /*text-align: center; */ /* REMOVE FROM HERE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the service-item divs, then it's the float:left causing the problem - remove this and it will centrally align.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `div.service-item` style

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/191/

CSS:

```
div.services-container {
      margin-top: 1em;
      overflow:hidden;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  div.service-items {
      max-width: 1280px;
      overflow:hidden;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  div.service-item {
      border:1px solid black;
      width:45%;
      padding: 1em;
      margin:0 auto;      
      text-align: center;
  }
```