# Unable to center DIVs within HTML Form

Tags: html, css

I've had no luck trying to center these 2 divs. I've tried the suggestion in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341223/unable-to-center-divs) with no success. I've also experimented with `margin: auto` and `width: 50%`. That gets me close, but it's not very centered, and when I adjust the width, the **Disabled** switch div ends up wrapping awkwardly to the next line, in spite of trying `text-align: center`.

[image]

```
<form method="post" action="Invitation.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
   <div style="width: 100%">
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
         <!-- Manual switch -->
         <div class="flipswitch" style="float: left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitchRecurring" id="flipswitchRecurring" class="flipswitch-cb" onclick="flipSwitch(this)">
            <label class="flipswitch-label" for="flipswitchRecurring">
               <div class="flipswitch-inner"></div>
               <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
         <!-- Disabled switch -->
         <div class="flipswitch2" style="float: left; margin-left: 35px">
            <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitchEnabled" id="flipswitchEnabled" class="flipswitch2-cb">
            <label class="flipswitch2-label" for="flipswitchEnabled">
               <div class="flipswitch2-inner"></div>
               <div class="flipswitch2-switch"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

How can I center these 2 DIVs?

Comment: You are floating them left

Comment: Yes. When I remove the `float:left` it makes them worse, they wrap, stay on the far left, jumbled one on top of the other.

Comment: `display:flex; align-items:center; flex-direction:row;` on the parent. Remove the floats.

Comment: <div style="width: 100%;position:relative;display:inline-table;text-align:center;left:40%;right:40%;">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification to your code (Added `text-align:center` and `display:inline-block`) =>

```html
<form method="post" action="Invitation.php?AccessCode=5GR1A67833Y7W98UW8546FJM8" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
   <div style="width: 100%">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
         <!-- Manual switch -->
         <div class="flipswitch" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitchRecurring" id="flipswitchRecurring" class="flipswitch-cb" onclick="flipSwitch(this)">
            <label class="flipswitch-label" for="flipswitchRecurring">
               <div class="flipswitch-inner"></div>
               <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
         <!-- Disabled switch -->
         <div class="flipswitch2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitchEnabled" id="flipswitchEnabled" class="flipswitch2-cb">
            <label class="flipswitch2-label" for="flipswitchEnabled">
               <div class="flipswitch2-inner"></div>
               <div class="flipswitch2-switch"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual, what is a pain with classic CSS (float, inline-block, etc.) is a breeze with Flexbox.

```css
form {
  border: blue dashed 2px;
}

.centrer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switchBlock {
  border: red dashed 2px;
  width: 100px;
}

.switchBlock:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="Invitation.php?AccessCode=5GR1A67833Y7W98UW8546FJM8" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">

  <div class="centrer">
  
    <!-- Manual switch -->
    <div class="switchBlock flipswitch">
      <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitchRecurring" id="flipswitchRecurring" class="flipswitch-cb" onclick="flipSwitch(this)">
      <label class="flipswitch-label" for="flipswitchRecurring">
               <div class="flipswitch-inner"></div>
               <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
            </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Disabled switch -->
    <div class="switchBlock flipswitch2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitchEnabled" id="flipswitchEnabled" class="flipswitch2-cb">
      <label class="flipswitch2-label" for="flipswitchEnabled">
               <div class="flipswitch2-inner"></div>
               <div class="flipswitch2-switch"></div>
            </label>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</form>
```